# Check if a range corresponding to another range is blank or not

Tags: excel

I need to check if a range corresponding to another range is blank or not.
[image]

e.g. I need to check if range (B1:B3) which is corresponding to range (A1:A3) (Criteria: ="A") contains blank cells or not.

I tried Sumproduct but no luck as it it dosn't distinguish between blank and 0.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is

```
=Countifs(A1:A13,"=A",B1:B13,"<>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use COUNTBLANK(B1:B3)

Check out
http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/count-blank-nonblank-cells.html